# Problems with isset() and $_SESSION variables

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm currently working on a project that requires session variables to store search information, which is pretty common place. Typically, I've used isset() to check if a session variable exists. However, there seems to be a problem that is bewildering...not sure what is going on. Any help is appreciated. The code...

```
<?php
# Check to make sure the session is started 
if (session_id() != '') echo 'Session has started<br/>';
# Check every possible way I know to make sure variable is set
if (array_key_exists('adminsearchrange', $_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['adminsearchrange']) 
    && !empty($_SESSION['adminsearchrange']) && $_SESSION['adminsearchrange'] != NULL) {
    echo 'Search range is set and is not empty<br/>';
    echo $_SESSION['adminsearchrange'];
}
?>
```

The output...

```
Session has started
Search range is set and is not empty
Notice: Undefined index: adminsearchrange in /Users/.../events_items.php on line 1182
```

Based on the comments, I took the simplest approach...created a new file whose entire contents is listed below. Still get the same error (above), and oddly enough, it still references the the exact line and file (even though that file is not being included in any way)...and no, there isn't any `.htaccess` rewriting of any sort. The code (all in one file)...

```
<?php
session_start();
if (session_id() != '') echo 'Session has started<br/>';
if (array_key_exists('adminsearchrange', $_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['adminsearchrange']) 
    && !empty($_SESSION['adminsearchrange']) && $_SESSION['adminsearchrange'] != NULL) {
    echo 'Search range is set and is not empty<br/>';
    echo $_SESSION['adminsearchrange'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you know which is the offending clause in your if statement?  I would start removing each, starting with the last, until I don't get this error, then at least we have a good starting place.

Comment: not sure if this is needed but try putting `session_start();` at the beginning

Comment: We assume you did `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see what's in there...

Comment: And `echo $_SESSION['adminsearchrange'];` is 110% definitely `on line 1182`?

Comment: At the line of the error is the session variable definitely correct (no typos) and are you using session_start() in that file?

Comment: @Michael You assumed correctly. `var_dump($_SESSION)` shows no indication of `adminsearchrange`. So, it isn't in the array, but still passes the check.

Comment: @Henesnarfel Yes, there is a `session_start()` in the code, and there are items in the `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: strip *all* the rest of the code, so you only have session_start and the posted code. does it still happen?

Comment: It appears the session was hosed (somehow). A simple `session_destroy()` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the session was hosed (somehow). A simple `session_destroy()` solved the problem.